# Como obfuscar um e-mail em PHP preenchendo parte dos caracteres antes do @ (arroba) com * (asterísco)?

Tags: php, string

Eu preciso de obfuscar os caracteres do e-mail, como já vi muitos sites fazendo, preenchendo alguns caracteres desse e-mail com asterisco.

Eu gostaria que o código fosse o mínimo completo possível.

Exemplo:

```
 'wallacemaxters@teste.com' => 'wa*********rs@teste.com'
```

Como fazer isso de maneira bem simples?

Comment: PS: eu pensei que talvez usar o `substr_replace` fosse uma boa ideia

Answer (score 3):

Eu pensei em elaborar de maneira bem simples usando a função `substr_replace` combinada com `strpos`.

Veja:

```
$mail = 'wallacemaxters@teste.com'

substr_replace($mail, '*****', 1, strpos($mail, '@') - 2);
```

O Resultado é

```
'w*****s@teste.com'
```

A explicação do código é a seguinte: o terceiro argumento (`1`) faz com que a posição a ser substituída seja a partir do primeiro caractere. Já o quarto argumento `strpos($mail, '@')` nos dará a posição final onde deve ser substituída, que é o `@`. Nesse caso, usei o `-2` para que nem o `@` nem o último caractere antes dele fosse substituído.

O tamanho da substituição será determinado a partir da posição inicial. Se fosse necessário exibir 2 caracteres no início e 2 antes do `@`, teríamos que alterar a função da seguinte forma:

```
substr_replace($mail, '*****', 2, strpos($mail, '@') - 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar `sub_str_replace()` para inidicar onde e quantos caracteres substituir e `str_repeat()` para gerar a string que substituira o email original.

```
function ofuscaEmail($email, $inicio, $qtd){
  $asc = str_repeat('*', $qtd);
  return substr_replace($email, $asc, $inicio, $qtd);
}

$str = 'wallacemaxters@teste.com';
echo ofuscaEmail($str, 2, 8);
```

Comment: Cara, bacana essa solução, mas eu acho que você deveria adaptar de uma forma que fique antes do `@`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters daqui a pouco já acerto.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer através da função [**preg_replace**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Com a `regex` abaixo você consegue agrupar os dois primeiros caracteres e os dois caracteres anteriores ao `@`.

```
^([\w_]{2})(.+)([\w_]{2}@)
```

Com o poder do `regex` você poderá criar regras bastantes específicas para seu problema.

```
<?php

$pattern     = "/^([\w_]{2})(.+)([\w_]{2}@)/u";
$replacement = "$1********$3";
$email       = "wallacemaxters@teste.com";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $email);

//Output: wa********rs@teste.com
```

E com a mesma `regex`, você também poderá utilizar a função [**preg_replace_callback**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) e trabalhar com mais liberdade utilizando uma função específica para determinado problema.

```
<?php

function ocultarEmail($matches)
{
    return $matches[1] .
        str_repeat("*", strlen($matches[2])) .
        $matches[3];
}

$pattern     = "/^([\w_]{2})(.+)([\w_]{2}@)/u";

for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $email       = str_repeat("a", $i)."@teste.com";
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'ocultarEmail', $email);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Demonstração**](https://ideone.com/TfMDSi)